# How is the frequency for a CR Filter acting as a Differentiator Determined?

Tags: capacitor

The CR filter looks like:

[image: CR Differentiator]

It is a High pass filter, so can the frequency be calculated by using the following equation?
\$ f_{0} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi CR}\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The* frequency doesn't exist, I guess you mean **cutoff frequency**. Yes, that's the equation for it. If you draw a Bode diagram you'll have a 6dB/octave (20dB/decade) slope below \$f_C\$, and flat for frequencies above it.

[image]

Comment: The exact question says:
Estimate the frequency range for which the C-R circuit shown in Figure 1(a) will act as a differentiator. 
Where in the circuit values for C-R are given. And no source links frequency to a differentiator circuit.

Comment: Aw man, diagrams!  Where'd you get that/make it?  That is (if I may say) straight up dope.

Comment: @AngryEE - Well, a picture's worth a thousand words, doesn't it? Saves me typing all that stuff. :-) Where I got it? images.google.com + the right keywords

Answer (score 1):

Yes - that's correct. The only difference between this and the low-pass variant is that the low-pass has a pole, this has a zero. Of course, it isn't a perfect high-pass filter.  Parasitic capacitance and inductance in the elements will cause this to realistically be a bandpass filter.  (I included that disclaimer in case anyone gets any funny ideas about this being a perfect high-pass filter).

Also, if you're interested in what range this will work as a differentiator, that will NOT be all the way up to the corner frequency.  Differentiation relies on changes in phase so you need to make sure that the phase shift applied to the signal is 90 degrees.  At the -3dB point the phase will be 45 degrees.  You need to step back at least one decade from the corner frequency to ensure your phase will be 90 degrees.